# spring-mail-starter ignoring spring.mail.* config

Tags: email, spring-boot, properties, jakarta-mail

I have a project using spring-boot and added
the following dependency in my build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '1.5.7.RELEASE'
```

My application.properties contains

### SMTP Configuration

```
spring.mail.host=mail.xxx
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=donotreply@xxx
spring.mail.password=xxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from=donotreply@xxx
```

According to multiple answers here and documentations i found,that should be enought to create the bean with this settings.

I now want to use a mailer in a Service class

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender emailSender;
[...]

@Value("${spring.mail.host}")
private String mailHost;
```

When i try to send a message using emailSender i get the following error:

> Mail server connection failed; nested exception is
> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
> port: localhost, 25; timeout -1; nested exception is:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed
> messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to
> host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1; nested exception is:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Obviously it is trying to connect to localhost instead of the configured host.
The variable mailHost does contain the correct value, so the properties are read correct.

EDIT:
The autowired class for emailSender is org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl, which seems to be correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, the reason was that I instantiated the bean myself like this:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender mailSender() throws IOException {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return mailSender;
}
```

Not sure why, but that way, it ignores the `application.properties`. Maybe the reason was, that I explicitly instantiated JavaMailSender**Impl** to set a default encoding and possibly that implementation isn't `application.properties` aware?

However, removing that bean solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[FOUND]
A co-worker was working on the same and had commited an incomplete bean definition. That bean was autowired.